# Не скачивается файл по ссылке

Tags: html, html5

Помогите пожалуйста в таком вопросе.

У меня на форме есть ссылка с атрибутом download. Код ниже:

```
<a download href="/home/sergey/Downloads/myFile.txt">Download</a>
```

Но когда я нажимаю на форме на ссылку, файл скачивается, но пишет Failed - No file. Фото ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема скорее всего в том что Вы указываете ссылку на файл на диске а не в директории веб сервера

Comment: Немного не понял. Как же я укажу в директории с сервером, если файл лежит на диске?

Comment: Положить файл в директорию, которую хостит веб сервер, иначе любой посетитель Вашего сайта мог бы скачать любой файл с Вашего диска (это дыра)

Comment: Да, это я сделал на сервере, но там и была эта ошибка.

Решил проверить на обычном примере как работает download атрибут.

Создал обычный html файл и указал путь к файлу на моём компьютере. И всё равно ошибка.

Comment: какую директорию раздает Ваш веб сервер наружу?

Comment: Вы были правы, спасибо.

Я не учёл директорию веб сервера.

Comment: нет проблем, обращайтесь

Answer (score -1):

`<a href="/home/sergey/Downloads/myFile.txt" download>Download</a>`
Также download может не работать в IExplorer